# How to load libraries that use composer?

Tags: php, installation, dependencies, composer-php

I am trying to use https://github.com/php-loep/oauth2-client as an oauth 2.0 libary.

It has dependencies that need to be installed using composer.

I tried to follow the manuals and everything seemed fine, however I am just unable to get it to work!

I cloned the repository to a folder where I downloaded composer and installed the dependencies.
This generated a unique autoload file.

Now it is my understanding that I only need to require this autoload file and should be good to go. That is what I did, however it cannot resolve the class name of the class that I need to load. In my case this would be `\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Facebook`

The usage of the library is documented here: https://github.com/php-loep/oauth2-client/blob/master/README.md

To make sure that I give no ambiguous information, I created this short shell script (Scripts dont lie!) which reproduces the steps I took. If i run it in an empty folder and then run the created file `foo.php` from command line or web browser, I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth2\Client\Provider\Facebook' not found in /var/www/test/foo.php on line 1`

Heres the script...

```
git clone https://github.com/php-loep/oauth2-client.git
cd oauth2-client
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
cd ..
echo "<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); require_once 'oauth2-client/vendor/autoload.php'; \$provider = new \OAuth2\Client\Provider\Facebook(array()); " > foo.php
```

What did I do wrong? Have I misunderstood the concept of composer? If so, please enlighten me!

I also tried moving the file `foo.php` to into the folder `oauth2-client`, that changed nothing.

I am running php 5.3 and the `__DIR__` constant is also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foo.php, a wrong namespace is used for the Facebook class. You missed this part: `\League`.

oauth2-client/src/League/OAuth2/Client/Provider/Facebook.php:

```
namespace League\OAuth2\Client\Provider;

class Facebook extends IdentityProvider
{
```

Comment: sometimes the answer hides in plane sight -.- thank you. the road to hell is covered with copied and pasted plates :P

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it could be to do with namespaces. If you are running PHP 5.2 you will run into problems because namespaces are not supported prior to PHP 5.3 :(

Anyway to fix the issue you need to go into some of composers files and change a few things. Off the top of my head I had to edit the autoload_real.php to include the class loader and replace **DIR** with dirname(**FILE**). Not sure if this is the best way but I got it working by doing this.

Comment: thanks! +1 i am running php 5.3. the `__DIR__` constant is also available. what do you mean by "to include the classloader" ? and am I interpreting your response correctly insofar as that my usage of composer is basically correct?

Comment: Oh if you are running 5.3 then my answer doesnt help much!! I just meant include it using include() or require()